# In the file explorer preview pane how do I remove numbered lines from .txt files?

Tags: windows-explorer, windows-11, notepad, preview-pane

In Windows 11, how do I remove numbered lines from .txt/notepad files in the file explorer preview pane? Other files, like .docx, appear just fine. It's just .txt files that seem to have this line numbering. There's also a weird loading thing other files don't seem to have, despite the files being so much smaller (but I can't swear this is specific to .txt files, other things may also do this).

I remember I had the same problems in Windows 10, but I cannot remember how I fixed them. I know it's a minor thing, but it bugs me.

[example of the numbered lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JjIoC.png)

[example of loading text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CGEJw.png)

Answer (score 0):

It's due to PowerToys -> File Explorer add-ons -> Source code files